# solve equations with unknown variables in it in java

Tags: java, math

I need a function that takes in a equation in the form of a String,
for example: "a * b + 5 * a + 5 + a + 6" and simplifies it in for example:
"a * b + 6 * a +11".
but I can't make my own class work and I can't find a library for it.
I hoped people you could help me

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to search for Java Math Operators and Math Class or [libraries like this one](https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/#Examples)

Comment: @NikolayHristov I may be incorrect but I do not believe the Math Class has methods for condensing mathematical equations. Unless he is willing to download a non-standard library.

Comment: Additionally, will the equation involve parenthesis, division, exponents, etc.

Comment: I would want it to work with parenthesis, division and exponents, but if that is to complex it does not have to. I also do not want to download a library so if there is no build in library i am going to try writing my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Symja library](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) you can solve your problem like in this snippet:

```
package org.matheclipse.core.examples;

import org.matheclipse.core.eval.ExprEvaluator;
import org.matheclipse.core.expression.F;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IExpr;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.SyntaxError;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.math.MathException;

public class SimplifySO55169181 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ExprEvaluator util = new ExprEvaluator();
            IExpr result = util.eval("a * b + 5 * a + 5 + a + 6");
            // print: 11+6*a+a*b
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        } catch (SyntaxError e) {
            // catch Symja parser errors here
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (MathException me) {
            // catch Symja math errors here
            System.out.println(me.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a standard library for what you ask. However, here are some pointers:

1) Validity check:
       Remove all spaces(looping through each character adding it to a String if not space)
       Make sure all values are * or + or [letter] or [number]

2) Counting variables:
       Create a hashmap who's key is the variable and the value is the sum of the number of letters by looping through the string.

3) Counting variables based on multiplying (such as 6 * a). Loop through, see if variable as follows: [number]*[variable] or [variable]*[number]. Add the number - 1 (it was already counted once in step 2.

4) Count constants. Same as 3 except it would be [number]+[number].

5) Print it out in order you see fit.

I changed the pattern slightly. Additionally, for the program to work properly, variables must be lowercase and single characters. Division and subtraction have not been implemented although it would be fairly similar to most of the code. Lastly, the system expesct integers only to function properly.

```
package com.Bif.MathCondenser;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MathCondenser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //input equations
        String equation = "a * b + 10 * 3 + 50 * a + c * 3 * b * a * 4 * 3";
        String equation_temp = "";

        //constant character lists
        ArrayList<String> alphabet = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> functions = new ArrayList<String>();

        //equation separated into a list of products
        ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();

        //variable definitions of each product
        ArrayList<String> definitions = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> definitionsDuplicate = new ArrayList<String>();

        //collected constants for each product
        ArrayList<String> multipliers = new ArrayList<String>();

        //reduced terms for the equation
        ArrayList<String> terms = new ArrayList<String>();

        //fill alphabet arrayList
        for(char character = 'a'; character <= 'z'; ++character){
            alphabet.add(character-'a', character + "");
        }

        //fill numbers arrayList
        for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            numbers.add("" + k);
        }

        //fill functions arrayList
        functions.add("*");
        functions.add("+");

        //remove spaces from equation
        for(int k = 0; k < equation.length(); k++) {
            if(equation.charAt(k) == ' ')
                continue;
            equation_temp += equation.charAt(k);
        }
        equation = equation_temp;
        System.out.println("Equation: " + equation);

        //validate allowed characters; exit if not a-z, 0-9, or *,+
        for(int k = 0; k < equation.length(); k++) {
            if(!alphabet.contains(equation.charAt(k) + "") && !numbers.contains(equation.charAt(k) + "") && !functions.contains(equation.charAt(k) + "")) {
                System.out.println("Valid Characters: false, exiting");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Valid Characters: true, continuing");

        //parse the equation into sets of products
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(equation);
        scan.useDelimiter("\\+");
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            products.add(scan.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Product set:" + products);

        //fill definition such that (2 * b * a * 3 * c) -> (abc)
        String productAtLocationK;
        for(int k = 0; k < products.size(); k++) {
            productAtLocationK = products.get(k);
            String definition = "";
            for(int j = 0; j < productAtLocationK.length(); j++) {
                //if it is a letter add it to definition
                if(alphabet.contains(productAtLocationK.charAt(j) + "")) {
                    definition += productAtLocationK.charAt(j);
                }
            }

            //alphabetizes definition
            char[] tempDef = definition.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(tempDef);
            definitions.add(new String(tempDef));
            definitionsDuplicate.add(new String(tempDef));
        }

        System.out.println("Definition set: " + definitions);       

        //fill multiplier set such that (2 * b * a * 3 * c) -> (6)
        for(int k = 0; k < products.size(); k++) {          
            //get the product; default multiplier = 1; character at Location in product;
            productAtLocationK = products.get(k);
            int multiplier = 1;
            String letterInProduct;

            //set up scanner for every product in products array with * separator
            scan = new Scanner(productAtLocationK);
            scan.useDelimiter("\\*");

            //loop through product, if (not letter -> number) then update multiplier
            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                letterInProduct = scan.next();
                if(!alphabet.contains(letterInProduct)) {
                    multiplier *= Integer.parseInt(letterInProduct);
                }   
            }
            multipliers.add(multiplier + "");
        }
        System.out.println("Multiplier set: " + multipliers);

        //combine duplicate definitions
        int indexOfMultiplier = 0;
        while(!definitionsDuplicate.isEmpty()) {
            //sum of the constant and its duplicates to combine terms
            int constantSum = Integer.parseInt(multipliers.get(indexOfMultiplier++));
            String definition = definitionsDuplicate.remove(0);

            //check for duplicates, add them to sum
            while(definitionsDuplicate.contains(definition)) {
                constantSum += Integer.parseInt(multipliers.get(definitionsDuplicate.indexOf(definition)));
                definitionsDuplicate.remove(definitionsDuplicate.indexOf(definition));
            }

            //ignore constant if 1
            if(constantSum != 1)
                terms.add(constantSum + definition);
            else
                terms.add(definition);
        }
        System.out.println("Terms Set: " + terms);

        //Format equation
        String reducedEquation = "";
        for(String term : terms) {
            reducedEquation += term + " + ";
        }
        if(reducedEquation.length() > 1) {
            reducedEquation = reducedEquation.substring(0, reducedEquation.length() - 2);
        }
        System.out.println("Reduced Equation: " + reducedEquation);

        //cleanup
        scan.close();
    }

}
```